# Prove the inclusion that every uniformly continuous is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\left(X, d_X \right)$ and $\left(Y, d_Y \right)$ be metric spaces, let $M$ be a subset of $X$, and let $T \colon X \to Y$ be a mapping that is uniformly continuous on $M$. Then is $T$ also continuous on $M$?

Definition of Continuity:

Let $\left(X, d_X \right)$ and $\left(Y, d_Y \right)$ be metric spaces, let $T \colon X \to Y$ be a mapping, let $M$ be a subset of $X$, and let $p$ be a point of $X$. Then $T$ is said to be *continuous at point $p$* if, for every real numnber $\varepsilon > 0$, we can find a real number $\delta > 0$ such that $$d_Y\left( T(x), T(p) \right) < \varepsilon$$ for all points $x \in X$ for which $$ d_X(x, p) < \delta.$$

If $T$ is continuous at each point $p \in M$, then $T$ is said to be *continuous on set $M$*.

Finally, if $T$ is continuous on $X$, then $T$ is said to be continuous.

Definition of Uniform Continuity:

Let $\left(X, d_X \right)$ and $\left(Y, d_Y \right)$ be metric spaces, let $T \colon X \to Y$ be a mapping, and let $M$ be a subset of $X$. Then $T$ is said to be *uniformly continuous on $M$* if, for every real number $\varepsilon > 0$, we can find a real number $\delta > 0$ such that $$d_Y\left( T(x_1), T(x_2) \right) < \varepsilon$$ for all points $x_1, x_2 \in X$ for which $$d_X\left( x_1, x_2 \right) < \delta.$$

Are these two sets of definitions correct?

Further i want to prove the inclusion as mentioned above, only by definition, but unable to get it rightly.

Comment: The definitions are correct. Let $T \colon X → Y$ be uniformly continuous. Let $ε > 0$ be a real number and $p ∈ X$ be any point. Now, you need to find some real $δ > 0$ such that for all $x ∈ X$, $d_X(x,p) < δ ⇒ δ_Y(T(x),T(p)) < ε$. Any ideas what $δ$ you may pick?

Comment: If $\delta$ is $\epsilon/2$?

Comment: No. You have to use the fact that $T$ is uniformly continuous. Can you see how?

Comment: yeah sure, it would be helpful if you elaborate

Comment: Well, you got some $ε > 0$ and need to find some $δ > 0$ (with some properties). How may these two relate to the definition of uniformly continuity (as fulfilled by $T$)?

Comment: Well, what my understanding is that we are provided with uniform cont. (as mentioned also by you earlier), we need to take that definition to the next level of proving it to be continuous, the question is as there is a technical difference between them, so how could it lead us to continuity?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I think about it, without too many calculations:

Continuity means that for any $\epsilon$ and any $x$ it must be possible to find a $\delta$ that works. Uniform continuity means that for any $\epsilon$ it's possible to find a single $\delta$ that works for all $x$ simultaneously. Clearly, if you're given an $\epsilon$ and an $x$, and you know that can find a $\delta$ that works for all $x$ simultaneously, then you can find one that works for your specific $x$.

Comment: yeah that is what i know, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hXkQqCBLRp8&t=70s , but i want to prove the inclusion only via definition

Answer (score 0):

There is no way I am saying anything different from Aurthur, but, maybe this would explain it:

$T$ is said to be *continuous at point $p$* if, for every real numnber $\varepsilon > 0$, we can find a real number $\delta(p) > 0$ such that $$d_Y\left( T(x), T(p) \right) < \varepsilon$$ for all points $x \in X$ for which $$ d_X(x, p) < \delta(p).$$

What this means is that for continuous functions all you need is to find such a $\delta(p)$ that would work at the point p, and *your choice for $\delta$ can depend on the point at which you are proving continuity.*

Now, uniform continuity is a much stronger condition, as it requires a one size fit all $\delta$. 
It says that $T$ is  *uniformly continuous on $M$* if, for every real number $\varepsilon > 0$, we can find a real number $\delta^* > 0$ such that $$d_Y\left( T(x_1), T(x_2) \right) < \varepsilon$$ for all points $x_1, x_2 \in X$ for which $$d_X\left( x_1, x_2 \right) < \delta^*.$$

What this means is that for all $p\in M$, once we put $p=x_1$ and $\delta(p)=\delta^*$ from right above, our job of finding the small enough $\delta$ required for continuity at p is done! (Note to you: Look at where the quantifiers lie)